# Centrar un botón de un form en un div

Tags: html, css

Tengo un botón `<input type="submit">` dentro de un formulario y de un `div`. El `div` tiene un ancho especificado y también un padding. Quiero que el botón se muestre totalmente centrado en el div pero no lo consigo.

Aquí el código

```css
.dVolver {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dVolver">
  <form method="POST" action="creatabla.php">
    <input type="submit" value="VOLVER">
  </form>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="dVolver">
  <input type="submit" value="VOLVER">
</div>
```

Vaya, resulta que si ejecutan el código aquí lo ven correctamente, pero si lo prueban en Chrome o Firefox verán que en el primer `div` el botón VOLVER no está centrado, en la parte inferior hay más espacio que en la parte superior. En el segundo div sí se ve centrado el botón porque he eliminado el formulario, pero necesito el formulario, no lo puedo eliminar.

¿Por qué no sale centrado correctamente?

Comment: Saludos lo he probado en firefox y se encuentra perfectamente centrado, quiza deberias revisar si no posees otras clases que esten afectando a este elemento..!!

Comment: Eliminaste caché en ambos navegadores? Verificaste que no tuvieras otro css u otra clase que estuviera sobrescribiendo tus estilos?

Comment: No lo entiendo. No hay más código, sólo ese de más arriba, el css y el html... Aquí lo tengo subido y tampoco se ve correctamente centrado: http://waswas.byethost7.com/pruebas/pru.php

Comment: Lo he probado en dos ordenadores y en un móvil y esto es lo que yo veo: http://waswas.byethost7.com/pruebas/no%20centrado.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón seria que en el primer div tenes dos elementos, y en el segundo un solo elemento proba quitándole la clase al div y colocándole la misma clase al form

Comment: Colocando la clase al form sí que funciona. Gracias!

Comment: @bayocr Agrega lo que comentas en tu respuesta, sería de ayuda para los miembros de la comunidad, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container1{
  display: table;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}

.container2{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda par otros usuarios. Por favor, añade una descripción con lo que hace el código compartido y cómo soluciona el problema de la pregunta. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Si querés centrar todo dentro del elemento *div*, primero tenés que colocar todo dentro del mismo y después simplemente le agregas los siguientes estilos al *div*:

```css
.contenedor{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  
  <!-- CONTENIDO DEL DIV -->
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo con **line-height;**

```css
.dVolver {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 400px;
  line-height:200px;
}
 input {
  line-height:200px;
 }
```

Es un valor que controla el espacio entre líneas con valores de porcentane relativos. Funciona dándole el mismo valor a ambos elementos.